# How come my IBAction isn't connecting?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ibaction

So in my attached image I show my subclass I'm creating for my HOME button. I have many VCs with a HOME button and I want to connect them to this class to make them all send the user HOME

So far, I made my button to take this class, as shown in the image. My issue is I'm not able to connect my IBAction here and not sure why.... would appreciate any tips anyone can tell me about why I'm not able to connect my IBAction function to the button right now....

Another confusing thing is that although I haven't given any of the other buttons in this stackview of buttons a class, I'm actually able to connect any of my other buttons in this stackview to my IBAction... which I find odd.

[image]

```
class HomeButton: UIButton {
    @IBAction func showHomeVC(sender: AnyObject) {
        var sb: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        var vc: UINavigationController = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeNC-ID") as! UINavigationController
        self.present(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I'm aware that I can simply go to each VC where there's a HOME button and create an IBAction from each and just paste this code in there and it will work, but I would like to do this another way where I don't have to have so much of the same code being repeated.... I would like to know what changes need to be made to make this happen.

Comment: Basics: self.presentViewController...

Comment: any idea why when i drag the ibaction it doesn't let me link to the highlighted button though but it lets me link to all the other buttons in that stackview?

Comment: First, don't use a picture to show your code.  Second, what do you mean by dragging the IBAction?  Are you talking about connecting IBAction in code to a button in Interface Builder?  If so, I don't think you can under Xcode 8 to my knowledge.

Comment: ok. well, yes, that is what I meant, and I've tried the other ways that are normally used to create an IBAction; it won't even let me create an IBAction if I drag from the button in Interface Builder to the code, nor will it let me if I drag from the most left pane to the code.

Comment: also, even with the self there it shows the error "Value of type 'HomeButton' has no member 'present'

Comment: i changed it from presentViewController to present since I'm on xcode 8

Comment: Take a look at Line 23.  You are doing it all wrong.

Comment: That's what I was thinking but I'm not sure which route to take. My goal is to create a class that can be used for all the HOME buttons on all the other VCs. What do I need to change?

Comment: Set IBActions and IBOutlets with a view controller, not a button.

Comment: okay. so i should completely remove the IBAction. How shall I ensure it knows the button is pressed then?

Comment: I think you should use Tab Bar Controller to show multiple view controllers, one tab bar button click it will show respective button. It is way far easy to use Tab Bar Controller rather than using multiple buttons.

Comment: I know but I'm just doing this for practice

Answer (score 3):

The error that you are are getting is because you are using the class of UIButton which doesn't have the property to display a view controller. You should present it either on a UIViewController, or one of the other types.

It is linked up but you just can't present a view controller using self (UIButton)

Comment: Hello Trever. Thank..... Okay, I understand the 1st sentence. I am confused on the 2nd sentence however. Would you be so kind to elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Sure! UIButton doesn't have a method to call present on, these are reserved for things like UIViewController or UITableViewController, etc. basically for Views.